# Gradle rule-based model nested beans syntax

Tags: gradle, groovy, dsl

I want to try [new rule based configuration in Gradle](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/software_model.html) to configure my plugin. Plugin's purspose is uploading data to cloud storages, like Google Drive or S3. I need a configuration for each storage the user want's to use. So, what I want to achieve is:

```
model {
    backup { // this is a container for all storages I want to support
        googleDrive {
            clientId = ''
            clientSecret = ''
            accessToken = ''
            refreshToken = ''
        }

        s3 {
           // S3 specific config (like API keys)
        }
    }
}
```

In my plugin I configure rule source for `backup` element:

```
class BackupPlugin implements Plugin<Project> {

    static class Rules extends RuleSource {
        @Model
        void backup(BackupPluginExtension backupModel) {}
    }
}

@Managed
interface BackupPluginExtension {
    GoogleDrive getGoogleDrive()

    void setGoogleDrive(GoogleDrive googleDrive)
}

@Managed
interface GoogleDrive {
    String getClientId()

    void setClientId(String clientId)

    String getClientSecret()

    void setClientSecret(String clientSecret)

    String getAccessToken()

    void setAccessToken(String accessToken)

    String getRefreshToken()

    void setRefreshToken(String refreshToken)
}
```

But, that doesn't work saying: `Could not find method googleDrive() for arguments [build_8w85xu7hrz3atgeg839d33hzl$_run_closure1_closure2_closure3@1b06ac95] on root project 'test'.`. Looks like it tries to call methods inside `backup` and not configure nested beans.

So, what is the correct syntax for that?

I know about named collections, but the question is how to configure custom bean hierarchies.

Comment: `build.gradle` from [here](https://github.com/Opalo/stackoverflow/tree/master/34359856) compiles well. Do you have an example of problematic file?

Comment: @Opal, no, it doesn't. `./gradlew build` may work because of lazy nature of Gradle, but `./gradlew model` forces to build model hierarchy and fails with: `No signature of method: BackupPluginExtension.googleDrive() is applicable for argument types: (build_dg6xcmwhd5yulrz1952ef2hf7$_run_closure1$_closure2$_closure3) values: [build_dg6xcmwhd5yulrz1952ef2hf7$_run_closure1$_closure2$_closure3@6b95c03e]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After playing with it for a while, it seems that making `googleDrive` *read-only* (i.e. by removing `setGoogleDrive()` setter) fixes your problem (I get *BUILD SUCCESSFUL* when running `gradle model`).

And after few minor modifications (using `@Mutate` instead of `Plugin.apply`), it looks like this:

```
apply plugin: BackupPlugin

class BackupPlugin extends RuleSource {
    @Model
    void backup(BackupPluginExtension backupModel) {
    }

    @Mutate void createTasks(ModelMap<Task> tasks, BackupPluginExtension model) {
        tasks.create("backup") {
            doLast {
                // ... do stuff
                println "googleDrive.clientId = ${model.googleDrive.clientId}"
            }
        }
    }
}

@Managed
interface BackupPluginExtension {
    GoogleDrive getGoogleDrive()

//    void setGoogleDrive(GoogleDrive googleDrive)
}

@Managed
interface GoogleDrive {
    String getClientId()

    void setClientId(String clientId)

    String getClientSecret()

    void setClientSecret(String clientSecret)

    String getAccessToken()

    void setAccessToken(String accessToken)

    String getRefreshToken()

    void setRefreshToken(String refreshToken)
}

model {
    backup { // this is a container for all storages I want to support
        googleDrive  {
            clientId = 'someId'
            clientSecret = ''
            accessToken = ''
            refreshToken = ''
        }

    }
}
```

Running `gradle backup` on this prints `googleDrive.clientId = someId`.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you! Just what I need.

Comment: Also, important note on this answer. It still doesn't work with Gradle 2.9 (I used that version when asked the question), but works in 2.12. So, the problem was not only the syntax, but they have changed something inside Gradle too :)

Answer (score 3):

Here is a model example of bean hierarchy collection inspired from Gradle package `samples/modelRules/ruleSourcePluginEach/`.

`BackupStorage` contains common attributes for both `GoogleDrive` and `S3` storages.

```
apply plugin: BackupPlugin

model {
    backup {
        storage1(GoogleDrive) {
            clientId = '1'
            clientSecret = ''
            accessToken = ''
            refreshToken = ''
        }
        storage2(S3) {
           clientId = '2'
        }
        storage3(GoogleDrive) {
            clientId = '3'
            clientSecret = ''
            accessToken = ''
            refreshToken = ''
        }
    }
}

class BackupPlugin implements Plugin<Project> {

    void apply(Project p) { }

    static class Rules extends RuleSource {
        @Model void backup(ModelMap<BackupStorage> bs) {
        }
    }
}

@Managed
interface BackupStorage {
    String getClientId()
    void setClientId(String clientId)
}

@Managed
interface GoogleDrive extends BackupStorage {
    String getClientSecret()
    void setClientSecret(String clientSecret)

    String getAccessToken()
    void setAccessToken(String accessToken)

    String getRefreshToken()
    void setRefreshToken(String refreshToken)
}

@Managed
interface S3 extends BackupStorage {
}
```

Comment: This works too, but I've accepted another answer as it is exactly what I wanted to achive.